# Can not resolve symbol ParseLoginBuilder

Tags: android, android-studio, parse-platform, build.gradle

According to [parse official site](http://blog.parse.com/2014/06/25/login-love-for-your-android-app/) i am using Parse Library(Parse-1.6.0) in my project. In the Mainfest file i used

```
<activity
        android:name="com.parse.ui.ParseLoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/log_in"
        android:launchMode="singleTop">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.parse.ui.ParseLoginActivity.PARSE_LOGIN_ENABLED"
            android:value="true" />
    </activity>
```

and used this in appropriate java file(TodoListActivity).

```
ParseLoginBuilder builder = new ParseLoginBuilder(this);
        startActivityForResult(builder.build(), LOGIN_ACTIVITY_CODE);
```

Can not resolve symbol ParseLoginActivity and can not resolve symbol ui is being displayed in manifest and can not resolve symbol ParseLoginBuilder in Activity. com.parse.ui.ParseLoginBuilder package doe'n exist.

**GradleConsole**[image]
**Messages Gradle Build**
[image]
**build.gradle**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the library is not on your classpath. 
You should either define it as a dependency in your build.gradle if it's available in some of the public repositories, or import the jar into the android studio project.

EDIT: It seems from their website that it's not published in Maven central, so you should probably import the jar into the project.

Comment: I imported jar and i defined in build.gradle. All the imports of Parse are working fine but ony (import com.parse.ui.ParseLoginBuilder;) is not working.

Comment: Posting the relevant part of your build.gradle would help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
just go to your dependency settings and add ParseUI as a dependency to your project.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I encountered this problem because I had not added the 'ParseLoginUI' project on the build path since I'm using Ecplise.

I downloaded the 'ParseLoginUI' from [here](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseUI-Android), extracted and then imported the 'ParseLoginUI' folder into eclipse as a project. I then added it to my other app as a project on the build path:

project properties > java build path > Projects tab > add > select 'ParseLoginUI'.

After I did this the error on "ParseLoginBuilder cannot be resolved..." and on the import statement, disappeared after a clean and rebuild.